# How to remove Application Request Routing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis

I have problem because Application Request Routing 2.5 doesn't root my requests anymore on my windows 7 with IIS 7.

I don't know how to remove it and reinstall it. It's impossible with Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

Does someone know ?

Comment: Please do not cross post. If we think a question should be on another site, we will move it. Thank you. (Mods: We're closing [it on SF](http://serverfault.com/q/436475), you can have it)